# java BigDecimal result not the desired one

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to write a program that calculates an expression such as "3+(6/5)+(2*3/7)*7/2*(9/4+4*1)=", where the order of precedence is as it is written. The only thing that matters is that if there is a sub-expression present within brackets, they should be calculated first.

My code is okay to some extent but the final result is not what it's desired. For example "3+(6/5)+(2*3/7)*7/2*(9/4+4*1)=" should print 110.63 but it prints 110.69.
"4+6/5+(4*9-8)/7*2=" prints 8.58 but should be 8.57.
I'm almost certain that it has something to do with the rounding but I'm not really sure and can't think of a solution since I'm fairly new to BigDecimal or even programming in general.

PS: It works fine with doubles but I'm receiving runtime errors while running unknown tests on a certain platform for testing, so I thought I'd try with BigDecimal in case it's because of too many numbers after the decimal point but oh, well..

Heres my code:

```
    String nc = scan.nextLine();
    BigDecimal j = new BigDecimal(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < nc.length(); i++) {
        if (nc.charAt(i) == '(') {
            int startIndex = nc.indexOf("(");
            int endIndex = nc.indexOf(")");
            String toBeReplaced = nc.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
            String omg = toBeReplaced.replaceAll("\\(|\\)", "");
            BigDecimal ok = new BigDecimal(0);
            int m=0;
            String split[]=omg.split("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\=");
            for (int k = 0; k < omg.length(); k++) {
                if (k == 0) {
                    ok = new BigDecimal(split[0]);
                }
                if (omg.charAt(k) == '+') {
                    m++;
                    ok=ok.add(new BigDecimal(split[m]));
                } else if (omg.charAt(k) == '-') {
                    m++;
                    ok = ok.subtract(new BigDecimal(split[m]));
                } else if (omg.charAt(k) == '*') {
                    m++;
                    ok = ok.multiply(new BigDecimal(split[m]));
                } else if (omg.charAt(k) == '/') {
                    m++;
                    ok = ok.divide(new BigDecimal(split[m]),2,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
                }
            }
            nc = nc.replace(toBeReplaced, ok + "");
        }
    }
    String split[]=nc.split("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\=");
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nc.length(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            j = new BigDecimal(split[0]);
        }
        if (nc.charAt(i) == '+') {
            k++;
            j = j.add(new BigDecimal(split[k]));
        } else if (nc.charAt(i) == '-') {
            k++;
            j = j.subtract(new BigDecimal(split[k]));
        } else if (nc.charAt(i) == '*') {
            k++;
            j = j.multiply(new BigDecimal(split[k]));
        } else if (nc.charAt(i) == '/') {
            k++;
            j = j.divide(new BigDecimal(split[k]),2,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(j.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

Comment: `4+6/5+(4*9-8)/7*2` is equvalent to `4+(6/5)+((4*9-8)/7*2)`, which is `13.2`, not `8.58` or `8.57`.

Comment: Apart from the fact that all your calculations seem to be mathematically wrong as metioned, the difference in results between double and now using BigDecimal comes from the fact that when you divide you allways round to 2 places. This imprecision can make a huge difference if you do it early in an calculation. -- e.G: (1/3) * 300 is actually 100, but would be 99 if you round 1/3 to 0.33 early on.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i stated that the order of precedence is as it is written (e.g: it doesn't matter if it's first * or +). It doesn't need to be mathematically correct.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Well, if I don't round it it throws me an "Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result" and when I looked for a solution regarding that, the rounding was what i found. I didn't need to round it with doubles.

Comment: Yes, true. But you don't have to be so restrictive and round to 2 places. Use 10 or maybe even something higher instead and you're calculations will be a lot more precise. => `ok.divide(new BigDecimal(split[m]),10,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);`

Comment: Also, as a note: right now your implementation doesn't support nesting brackets, and it repeats itself twice.

Comment: Well, apparently the runtime errors were not related to wether it's BigDecimal or double, so if anyone has any idea in what case/s it might happen, I'd be grateful.